# When deleting an entry in my array of arrays, the program crashes in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, editing

I have a program that sorts/displays emojis in different category's. This program has an edit button where the user should be able to delete or move an "entry" then when they click done the program re-adjusts. The array(s) should update and so should the running totals at the bottom of each section.

I'm not sure where the problem lies. The error message is:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (4), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted)."

Current Code:

```
 import UIKit

class EmojiTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var emojis: [[Emoji]] = [
            
            [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Grinning Face", description: "A typical smiley face.", usage: "happiness"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Confused Face", description: "A confused, puzzled face.", usage: "unsure what to think; displeasure"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Heart Eyes", description: "A smiley face with hearts for eyes.", usage: "love of something; attractive"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Police Officer", description: "A police officer wearing a blue cap with a gold badge. He is smiling, and eager to help.", usage: "person of authority")],
            
            
            [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Turtle", description: "A cute turtle.", usage: "Something slow"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Elephant", description: "A gray elephant.", usage: "good memory")],
            
            
            [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Spaghetti", description: "A plate of spaghetti.", usage: "spaghetti")],
             
             
            [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Die", description: "A single die.", usage: "taking a risk, chance; game"),
            Emoji(symbol: "⛺️", name: "Tent", description: "A small tent.", usage: "camping"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Stack of Books", description: "Three colored books stacked on each other.", usage: "homework, studying"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Broken Heart", description: "A red, broken heart.", usage: "extreme sadness"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Snore", description: "Three blue \'z\'s.", usage: "tired, sleepiness"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Checkered Flag", description: "A black and white checkered flag.", usage: "completion")]
        ]
    
    let myTitles: [String] = ["PEOPLE", "ANIMALS", "FOOD", "OTHER"]
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
            
            let label = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect.init(x: 5, y: 5, width: headerView.frame.width-10, height: headerView.frame.height-10)
            label.text = myTitles[section]
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
            label.textColor = .gray
            headerView.addSubview(label)
            
            return headerView
        }
        
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 40
        }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
            
            let label = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect.init(x: 5, y: 5, width: headerView.frame.width-10, height: headerView.frame.height-10)
            label.text = ("Total Emojis: \(emojis[section].count)")
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            label.textColor = .gray
            headerView.addSubview(label)
            
            return headerView
        }
        
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 40
        }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    @IBAction func refreshData(_ sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        sender.endRefreshing()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return emojis.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return emojis[section].count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emojiCell", for: indexPath)

            let emoji = emojis[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(emoji.symbol) - \(emoji.name)"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = emoji.description

            return cell
        }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You clicked at \(indexPath)")
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You clicked emoji \(emojis[indexPath.row])")
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            emojis.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }

    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
        let movingEmoji = emojis.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
        emojis.insert(movingEmoji, at: to.row)
    }

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let vc = segue.destination as? EmojiDetailViewController {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                vc.emoji = emojis[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you delete an entire section but refreshes the table with deletion of only 1 row , so replace

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        emojis.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

With

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        emojis[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```